# Invalid property `xyz` of bean class[java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'xyz' is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

I'm new to Spring boot. I'm having trouble with javax based validations.
The controller expects list of json obj from POST endpoint. In the JSON request json array, 
if `engine` or `name` is null, I get correct 400 error. But, when `engine.type` 
or `engine.name` are null, it throws 500 exception with error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'engine' of bean class 
[java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'engine' is not readable or has an invalid 
getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of 
the setter?
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class CarController {
  @PostMapping(path = "/cars")
  public ResponseEntity<PostModelResponse> createModel(
          @Valid @RequestBody ArrayList<Car> cars)
          throws JSONException, ConstraintViolationException {
          ...
      return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

Car.java

```
class Car {
  @NotNull
  @Valid
  private Engine engine;

  @NotNull
  private String name;

  Cars(Engine engine, String name) {
    this.engine = engine;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName(){ return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}
  public Engine getEngine() { return engine; }
  public void setEngine(Engine engine){ this.engine = engine; }

}
```

Engine.java

```
class Engine {
  @NotNull
  private String type;
  @NotNull
  private String name;

  Engine(String type, String name) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getType() { return type; }
  public void setType(String type) { this.type = type; }
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}
}
```

CollectionValidator.java

```
public class CollectionValidator implements Validator {

    private final Validator validator;

    public CollectionValidator(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Collection col = (Collection) target;
        for ( Object obj : col ) {
            ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(validator, obj, errors);
        }
    }
}
```

ValidatorAdvice.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidatorAdvice {

    @Autowired
    protected LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.initDirectFieldAccess();
        binder.addValidators(new CollectionValidator(validator));
    }
}
```

Request/Responses: URL: http://localhost:8080/cars

1. POST Body: [{
   "name" : "Volvo",
   "engine" : {
     "type" : "v3",
     "name" : "volvo_engine"
   }
   }]

   Response: 200(OK)
2. POST Body: [{
   "engine" : {
     "type" : "v3",
     "name" : "volvo_engine"
   }
   }]

   Response: 400(Which is expected coz `name` is missing)
3. POST Body: [{"name" : "Volvo"}]

   Response: 400(Which is expected coz `engine` is missing)
4. POST Body: [{
   "name" : "Volvo",
   "engine" : {
     "name" : "volvo_engine"
   }
   }]

   Response: 500(I was expecting 400) with error:

   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'engine' of bean class 
     [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid 
     getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of 
     the setter?

I looked at other stackOverflow results before posting this. Everything works fine if I'm accepting `Car` object instead of `ArrayList<Car>`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The validator work on beans, not list; one possible solution is to wrap your list in a bean with the `@Valid` annotation on the list attribute:

```
public class MyList<E> {

    @Valid
    private List<E> list;

    public List<E> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<E> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

And validate in the controller with:

```
createModel(@Valid @RequestBody MyList<Car> cars)
```

Comment: I tried this as well. But, the response is same, it still throws 500 exception